# c# htmlAgilityPack read from id block until another id block

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

i have a html document like this

```
   <tr  id="__TOC_1">

                                <div id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_3_7899df20-f104-434d-a5e4-fa293412f5db">
                                    <div style="visibility:hidden">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                                <div>District name</div>
                                <div>July&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2019</div>
                                <div>Something</div>
                                <div>Something</div>
                                <div>Address</div>
                                <div>
                                    <div style="visibility:hidden">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div style="visibility:hidden">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                        </tr>

<tr>
                            <td class="style_6" >
                                <div class="style_7" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_4_d4d6">Apartment number.</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6" s>
                                <div class="style_7" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_5_87b456a7" >Personal account</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div class="style_7" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_6_2b05c0c6>Accrued</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6" >
                                <div class="style_7" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_7_f66f8084>Received</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
<tr>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>195</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>00060631402</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>155.63</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div">155.63</div>
                            </td>

    <tr>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>Total</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>30</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>0.00</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="style_6">
                                <div>271.04</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

and this code repeat n-time with __TOC_2...__TOC_3.. and next

i need to take district name, month date, skip next block and take all info until total

and i want to write it to my object

```
 public class PaymentInfo
{
    public string District { get; set; }

    public string PaymentDate { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}

 public class Payment
{
    public string ApartmentNumber { get; set; }

    public int PersonalAccount { get; set; }

    public decimal Accrued { get; set; }

    public decimal Received { get; set; }
}
```

i think i need to read form first id block until another, but i dont understand how i can stop and filter inforamation

Answer (score 0):

You get these nodes by xpath `starts-with`

```
//tr[starts-with(@id,'__TOC')]
```

Then do foreach these results to process each block with hard code:

- div array order to get district name, address,...
- div id `AUTOGENBOOKMARK_4`, `AUTOGENBOOKMARK_5` to get Apartment, Number,...